# How do I install sass on centos 5.9 with ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: installation, centos, ruby

I have CentOS 5.9 on an x86_64. I've installed ruby 1.8.7. Whenever I try to install sass I get an Error saying sass requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7. but that's what I have installed. This is the sequence done as user root:

```
~ #> gem install sass
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    sass requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7
~ #> ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [x86_64-linux]
~ #>
```

I don't understand. The ruby version IS 1.8.7, but I continue to get the error. Any clues, suggestions?